# Removing time-stamped items from a PriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm using a priority queue (`java.util.PriorityQueue<T>`) where items with the same priority need to be handled in a first-in first-out basis.

I have managed that fine by adding a timestamp member to the item being added to the queue that is incremented for each item added. (See [PriorityQueue has objects with the same priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731967/priorityqueue-has-objects-with-the-same-priority) and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html )

So using the FIFOEntry class from the docs I have

```java
 class FIFOEntry<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
     implements Comparable<FIFOEntry<E>> {
   final static AtomicLong seq = new AtomicLong();
   final long seqNum;
   final E entry;
   public FIFOEntry(E entry) {
     seqNum = seq.getAndIncrement();
     this.entry = entry;
   }
   public E getEntry() { return entry; }
   public int compareTo(FIFOEntry<E> other) {
     int res = entry.compareTo(other.entry);
     if (res == 0 && other.entry != this.entry)
       res = (seqNum < other.seqNum ? -1 : 1);
     return res;
   }
 }
```

What I'd like to do now is to be able to determine if an item is in the queue and/or to be able to remove an item from it. I can't directly use the `contains` or `remove` functions because the queue holds FIFOEntry objects, not `E` ojects.

The `contains(Object o)` and the `remove(Object o)` functions of the queue depend on the arguments' `o.equals(e)` function. I was able to remove items by adding the `equals()` function to the `FIFOEntry` class that only uses the `entry` member for comparison.

I need a better method than this because this new `equals` function breaks the "consistent with equals" rule.

Would it be better to create a new, separate class that has a member for entry (same type E) and move the `equals()` function to this other class? What about using a Comparator instead?

p.s. More context: this is to be used in Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the `hashcode`, `compareTo` and `equals` properly for the `E`  class (entry), then everything will work fine.

The `FIFOEntry` class above is an example of [`Composition`](http://www.journaldev.com/1325/what-is-composition-in-java-java-composition-example).

Like you can override the `equals` method as below.

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object o){
   if(!(o instanceof FIFOEntry)){
      return false;
   }
   FIFOEntry cp= (FIFOEntry) o;
   return cp.entry.equals(entry) && cp.seqNum.equals(seqNum);
}
```

The FiFOEntry `compareTo` will return `0` if the Entry objects set in the FIFOEntry class will have `same entry object reference` and the same seq number. Basically the same Object on itself.

The compareTo and equals consistency will depend on how you implement both of them in your `E` class.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Test123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        E x = new Test123.E(1);
        PrivateBlockingQueue queue = new Test123.PrivateBlockingQueue();
        FIFOEntry<E> e1 = new Test123.FIFOEntry<E>(x);
        FIFOEntry<E> e2 = new Test123.FIFOEntry<E>(new E(2));
        FIFOEntry<E> e3 = new Test123.FIFOEntry<E>(new E(1));

        queue.add(e1);
        queue.add(e2);
        queue.add(e3);

        System.out.println(queue.contains(x));
        while (true) {
            FIFOEntry<E> t = queue.poll();
            if (t == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (t.equals(e1)) {
                System.out.println("hi this is E1");
                System.out.println(t.compareTo(e1));
            }
            System.out.println(t.getEntry().getInt() + " " + t.seqNum);
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    static class PrivateBlockingQueue extends
            PriorityBlockingQueue<FIFOEntry<E>> {
        public boolean contains(E o) {
            Iterator<FIFOEntry<E>> itr = iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                FIFOEntry<E> x = itr.next();
                if (x.entry.equals(o)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    static class E implements Comparable<E> {
        final private Integer xyz;

        public E(int e) {
            this.xyz = e;
        }

        public Integer getInt() {
            return xyz;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof E)) {
                return false;
            }
            E test = (E) obj;
            return test.getInt() == xyz;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(E o) {
            if (xyz < o.getInt()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (xyz > o.getInt()) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    static class FIFOEntry<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements
            Comparable<FIFOEntry<E>> {
        final static AtomicLong seq = new AtomicLong();
        final long seqNum;
        final E entry;

        public FIFOEntry(E entry) {
            seqNum = seq.getAndIncrement();
            this.entry = entry;
        }

        public E getEntry() {
            return entry;
        }

        public int compareTo(FIFOEntry<E> other) {
            int res = entry.compareTo(other.entry);
            if (res == 0 && other.entry != this.entry)
                res = (seqNum < other.seqNum ? -1 : 1);
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof FIFOEntry)) {
                return false;
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            FIFOEntry cp = (FIFOEntry) o;
            return cp.entry.equals(entry) && cp.seqNum == seqNum;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As per your requirement to check if a class `E` exists or not in the priorityqueue and also to maintain equals and compareTo consistency, you can extend and overload the `contains` (and other places where equals will be called), check the above code snippet (edited it).

Comment: Each time a FIFOEntry is created the `seq` is increased and thus no two FIFOEntry objects will have the same `seqNum`, so the only time `compareTo` returns 0 is when comparing a FIFOEntry to itself (or after so many have been created that seq loops back to 0).

Comment: Yeah correct .. but if you override equals properly, there wont be any violation.

Comment: check my edit.. added a code snippet.. the compareTo and equals work consistent to each other...

Comment: I see you added `seqNum` to the fields checked in `FIFOEntry.equals`. This will make it difficult to look for `FIFOEntry`'s inside the queue since I'd have to find out what the sequence number is of the items already stored. The goal is to search for a `FIFOEntry` that is holding a given `E`.

Comment: Search for a FIFOEntry for a given E can give multiple results right? What do you exactly want to do? The answer was in context to the violation of compareTo and equals ..

Comment: My goal is to be able to know if an `E` is in the queue without having to know what sequence number it was added with.